# Batch File Search Then Encrypt

Tags: c++, batch-file, encryption

im currently trying to encrypt some files on my server, ive downloaded aescrypt and i can encrypt individual files with the following command

```
aescrypt -e -p apples picture.jpg
```

however i would like to be able to write a batch file which will look at files in a specific folder and encrypt them all individually.

I know how to scan for files using CMD

```
dir /S C:\work\*.docx > c:\report.txt
```

can someone tell me how i would go about using the stored files names with my encrypter.

i.e. read report.txt then use the file-names in the report.txt to encrypt them

i.e. if report has the following in it

```
work1.docx
work2.docx
work3.docx
work4.docx
```

the batch file would then generate the following

```
aescrypt -e -p apples work1.docx
aescrypt -e -p apples work2.docx
aescrypt -e -p apples work3.docx
aescrypt -e -p apples work4.docx
```

and then delete the originals

```
work1.docx
work2.docx
work3.docx
work4.docx
```

I'm sure this is really simple but I am new to this and still trying to learn so any advice would be appreciated.

i would be happy with either a batch file or C++

Comment: Can you please clarify which language you're after?  Your post says C++ but you tagged it with C#.  Did you have a preference?

Comment: im not to fussed what language it is to be honest,  i would rather c++ or even a batch file,

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with a batch file, you can try this to search through all files in a folder and encrypt/decrypt them.

To Encrypt + delete the originals, you can run these batch commands in encrypt.bat:

```
FOR %%G IN ("C:\work\*.docx") DO aescrypt -e -p apples "%%G"
FOR %%G IN ("C:\work\*.docx") DO DEL "%%G"
```

and then you can Decrypt them by running the following batch command in decrypt.bat:

```
FOR %%G IN ("C:\work\*.aes") DO aescrypt -d -p apples "%%G"
```

Hope that helps.

**Edit:**

Here's an update for you to search through sub-folders as well.  If you use C:\work\, this should encrypt/decrypt any .docx files in that folder plus any in sub-folders as well.

Encrypt:

```
FOR /R "C:\work\" %%G IN (*.docx) DO aescrypt -e -p apples "%%G"
FOR /R "C:\work\" %%G IN (*.docx) DO DEL "%%G"
```

Decrypt:

```
FOR /R "C:\work\" %%G IN (*.aes) DO aescrypt -d -p apples "%%G"
```

Also please note I fixed a typo in my answer above.  The %%G parameter at the end of the command needs to be enclosed in speech marks like "%%G" otherwise the command will fail if your filename has spaces in it.

Comment: this is good,, however, is there a way to scan all directories say in c:\work\ as there is maybe 60 folders for different departments.

Comment: Yep you can do that as well.  I just revised my answer for you with some updated commands.

Comment: Sorryu my last question is if i want to encrypt more then 1 filetype can i use either * . * or *. ?  Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using * . * since that might try encrypting some files you don't want to touch.  Instead, you can manually specify as many file formats as you want by separating them with a space.  For example, this should work: ... IN (*.txt *.pdf *.docx *.rtf *.etc) DO ...